Switching from PostgreSQL to MySQL
screenshot of the full errorasp.net core mvc + ef core application, used Postgre, but need to switch to MySQL.
During migration I get the following error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'uuid NOT NULL,
Username text NOT NULL,
Email character varying(255' at line 2
here is my code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace DbOptions.Models
{
    [Table("Users")]
    public class user_entity
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("Id")]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column("Username")]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column("Email")]
        [StringLength(255)]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column("phoneNumber")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string phoneNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column("passwordHash")]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string passwordHash { get; set; }

        public virtual List<order_entity> orders { get; set; } = new List<order_entity>();
    }
}


using DbOptions.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

namespace DbOptions.Configuration
{
    public class user_config : IEntityTypeConfiguration<user_entity>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<user_entity> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("Users");

            builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

            builder.Property(x => x.Id)
                .HasColumnType("VARCHAR(36)") // Изменено на VARCHAR(36)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(x => x.Username)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(255)
                .HasColumnType("VARCHAR(255)");

            builder.Property(x => x.Email)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(255)
                .HasColumnType("VARCHAR(255)");

            builder.Property(x => x.phoneNumber)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .HasColumnType("VARCHAR(50)");

            builder.Property(x => x.passwordHash)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(255)
                .HasColumnType("VARCHAR(255)");

            builder.HasMany(x => x.orders)
                .WithOne(a => a.User)
                .HasForeignKey(a => a.UserId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            builder.HasIndex(x => x.Email).IsUnique();
            builder.HasIndex(x => x.Username).IsUnique();
        }
    }
}


Don't judge strictly, I'm new to programming
Changed the config file, model file, appsettings, DI connection for MySQL

Did you create new migration files? If not: do so. When making moves like this it's best to start with a clean slate regarding migrations.

I've tried to start with a new migration several times, but the error persists.

Please post the exact and complete SQL statement and the complete error message.

Sorry for the stupid question, but what exactly do you mean when you talk about SQL statement, the error occurs during migration, the code in which (presumably there is an error is indicated in the description), a screenshot of the full error has been added to the description

I mean the SQL commands to create tables, indexes, etc. Your code creates at least one SQL statement/command that is not valid for MySQL. Please share that command/statement

MySQL doesn't have a uuid data type. You need a char (or varchar). You might encounter the same problem with other data types since PostgreSQL has a wider variety of types.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html
vs
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/data-types.html

tried using string and attribute char(36)/VARCHAR(36), the error persists, changed the type both in the config file and in the model

Then your migration files still think they are connecyed to postgresql.
